# How to access the league page

Tags: discussion, support

The layout of the users page changed recently. I cannot find a way to go to the league page. How can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the reputation area to the right of a user's page, you'll see a "top x% this month/year/quarter" etc link, that goes to the league.

It's only available on the parent user page, not on the meta user page.